# Android studio1.0.2(beta) sdk component not installed(windows)

Tags: android, android-studio

I want use android studio 1.0.2(beta) but when I execute it show this error message:

```
The following SDK components were not installed: addon-google_apis-google-21, source-19 and source-21
```

[image]

And when click on retry again show this message, How I can fix it?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: have you installed the sdk?

Comment: I set sdk location in enviroment variables

Answer (score 0):

Either install Android-19, 21, apis-21 from the Android SDK manager, or change your target and compile version to the one which you have already downloaded.

[From Android Studio, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html)

Comment: when I cancel above message and click on finish, android studio exit

Comment: You can also open SDK manager directly from your file system. For example, in Mac it is there at `/Users/{user_name}/Library/Android/sdk` by default.